# Ubuntu 18.04.5: cannot load module for Intel Wifi adapter

Tags: drivers, wireless, iwlwifi, secure-boot

I'm running an Acer notebook that comes with an Intel WiFi adapter. The included kernel does not support it natively, so I found some separate  drivers which are installed via dkms. Unfortunately when calling

```
modprobe iwlwifi
```

an error

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'iwlwifi': Required key not available
```

is returned.

I already found a solution to disable scure boot via mokutil, but this does not work for me here - when I do this, loading of the kernel fails at grub boot level and I can't get into it at all.

So...how can I fix that, how can I get my 18.04.5 working with the Wi-Fi 6 AX200 chip?

Thanks!

UPDATE: to all the "I'm so clever in closing questions"-people: my question was NOT answered somewhere else. The solution you linked to suggested to disable secure boot - which doesn't works with newer BIOS versions. Disabling secure boot via MOK prevents Ubuntu from booting at all. So thanks for closing this question while not understanding what really is going on!

Comment: There are multiple answers there. You can add yours too. And you can always disable Secure Boot in UEFI settings, that is the easiest way to solve it.

Comment: @Pilot6 no, there is NO way to disable UEFI on my notebook, this option is no longer available in BIOS, so I have to use it, wether I like or not!

Answer (score 0):

OK, finally I solved it using the following steps

- install package shim-signed
- execute update-secureboot-policy --enroll-key in terminal
- reinstall the iwlwifi-package/rebuild the DKMS modules
- now the process asks for a password
- reboot, select "Enroll MOK" and enter the password

Et voila, the kernel module is used!